# I am getting a linker error in my program about a function possible redefined?

Tags: c++

I am having a linker error which I cannot figure out why this is happening. I tried every solution that I could think of. I know the files, are long. please just go to the end of Vehicle.H and Truck.h for the last 2 functions that I think this is talking about.

The error says:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits > & __cdecl sdds::operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits > &,class sdds::Vehicle &)" (??5sdds@@YAAEAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV12@AEAVVehicle@0@@Z) already defined in Truck.obj    *

Here are my 4 files: Main.Cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Truck.h"
#include "Truck.h" // intentional
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Vehicle.h" // intentional

using namespace std;
using namespace sdds;


void printHeader(const char* title)
{
    char oldFill = cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "|> " << title << endl;

    cout.fill('-');
    cout.width(40);
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout.fill(oldFill);
}


void moveAndLoad(Truck& aTruck, const char* destination, double cargo)
{
    cout << aTruck << endl;
    aTruck.moveTo(destination);
    if (aTruck.addCargo(cargo))
        cout << "Cargo loaded!\n";
    else
        cout << "Adding cargo failed!\n";
    cout << aTruck << endl << endl;
}

void moveAndUnload(Truck& aTruck, const char* destination)
{
    cout << aTruck << endl;
    aTruck.moveTo(destination);
    if (aTruck.unloadCargo())
        cout << "Cargo unloaded!\n";
    else
        cout << "Unloading cargo failed!\n";
    cout << aTruck << endl << endl;
}



int main()
{
    {
        printHeader("T1: Vehicle");

        Vehicle aVehicle("VVV-111", 2010);
        cout << aVehicle << endl << endl;

        aVehicle.moveTo("Downtown Toronto");
        aVehicle.moveTo("Mississauga");
        aVehicle.moveTo("North York");

        cout << endl << aVehicle << endl << endl;

        printHeader("T2: Read/Write");
        cin >> aVehicle;
        cout << endl << aVehicle << endl << endl;
    }
    
    {
        printHeader("T3: Truck");

        Truck aTruck("T-1111", 2015, 5432, "Toronto HQ");
        cout << endl;

        moveAndLoad(aTruck, "Toronto Deposit", 2345);

        moveAndLoad(aTruck, "Montreal", 3456);

        moveAndLoad(aTruck, "New York", 4567);

        moveAndUnload(aTruck, "New Jersey");

        moveAndUnload(aTruck, "Toronto");


        printHeader("T4: Read/Write");
        cin >> aTruck;
        cout << endl << (Vehicle)aTruck;
        cout << endl << aTruck << endl << endl;
    }
    
}
```

Truck.H:

```
#ifndef SDDS_TRUCK_H_
#define SDDS_TRUCK_H_

#include "Vehicle.h"

using namespace std;
namespace sdds {

   class Truck: public Vehicle {

      double cargoMaxWeight;
      double cargoLoad;

   public: 

      Truck(const char* plate, int year, double capacity, const char* currentAddy);


      bool addCargo(const double cargo);

      bool unloadCargo();

      ostream& write(ostream& os)const; 

      istream& read(istream& in);   

   };


   ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Truck& N);

   istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Vehicle& N);

}

#endif
```

Truck.CPP:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include "Truck.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS




using namespace std;

namespace sdds {


   Truck::Truck(const char* plate, int year, double capacity, const char* currentAddy) : Vehicle (plate, year) {
      cargoLoad = 0;
      Vehicle::moveTo(currentAddy);
      
   }

   //mutator function const
   bool Truck:: addCargo(const double cargo) {

      if (cargoLoad != cargoMaxWeight) {
         cargoLoad += cargo;
         return true;
      }
      return false;

   }

   bool Truck:: unloadCargo() {

      if (cargoLoad != cargoMaxWeight) {
         cargoLoad = 0;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   //query func should be const
   ostream& Truck::write(ostream& os)const {
      os << "| " << getYear() << " | " << getplateNum() << " | " << getAddress() << " | " << cargoLoad << "/" << cargoMaxWeight;

         return os;
   }


   istream& Truck::read(istream& in) {

      Vehicle::read(in);
      cout << "Capacity: ";
      in >> cargoMaxWeight;
      cout << "Cargo: ";
      in >> cargoLoad;

      return in;
   }


   ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Truck& N) {
      N.write(os);

      return os;

   }

   istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Vehicle& N) {

      N.read(istr);
      return istr;

   }


}
```

Vehicle.H

```
#ifndef SDDS_VEHICLE_H_
#define SDDS_VEHICLE_H_

using namespace std;
namespace sdds {


   class Vehicle {

      char plateNum [9];
      char Address[64];
      int year;
      
   public:
      Vehicle(const char* p, int y);


      char getAddress() const;
      char getplateNum() const;
      int getYear() const;


      void moveTo(const char* address);
      ostream& write( ostream& os)const;
      istream& read(istream& in);

   };

   ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vehicle& N);

   istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Vehicle& N);




}

#endif
```

Vehicle.CPP

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Vehicle.h"

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS


using namespace std;

namespace sdds {

   //sets address to factory
   Vehicle::Vehicle(const char* p, int y) {

      strcpy_s(plateNum, p);
      year = y;
      strcpy_s(Address, "Factory");
   }
   
   //returns year
   int Vehicle::getYear() const {
      return year;
   }


   //return plate number
   char Vehicle::getplateNum() const {
      return plateNum[9];
   }

   //returns Address
   char Vehicle::getAddress() const {
      return Address[64];
   }

   //changes location of vehicle to new address
   void Vehicle::moveTo(const char* address) {
      int result = strcmp(address, Address);

      if (result != 0) {
         cout  << plateNum << " |  | " << Address << "  ---> " << address << " |" << endl;
         strcpy_s(Address, address);

      }

   }

  //query func is cont
   ostream& Vehicle::write( ostream& os)const {

      os << "| " << year << " | " << plateNum << " | " << Address << endl;

      return os;

   }


   istream& Vehicle::read(istream& in) {

      cout << "Built year: ";
      in >> year;
      cout << "License plate: ";
      in >> plateNum;
      cout << " Current location: ";
      in >> Address;

      return in;
   }

   ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vehicle& N) {

      N.write(os);
      return os;

   }


   istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Vehicle& N) {
      
      N.read(istr);
      return istr;

   }

}
```

Please help!

Comment: Im not sure what a makefile is...im still a newbie to these terminologies. But I am using VS to build it.

Comment: The error is pretty clear IMHO, you've defined the same function twice....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined

```
   istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Vehicle& N) {

      N.read(istr);
      return istr;

   }
```

twice, once in each `.cpp` file.

Change or delete one of these to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Vehicle& N);

is defined in namespace sdds twice see your headers Vehicle.h and Truck.h, maybe by mistake.

in the Truck.h

change

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Truck& N);
istream& operator>>(istream& istr, **Vehicle**& N);

with

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Truck& N);
istream& operator>>(istream& istr, **Truck**& N);

here hope it is clear you should fix cpp as well

Comment: I recommend strengthening this answer with a solution to the problem.

Comment: This was intentional. If I remove the namespace sdds, there will be more errors. I am required to keep them in an sdds namespace.

Comment: technically yes, but he wanted 4 stream operators 2 for trucks and 2 for vehicles